# Select a portion if only several conditions are met in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have simple equations where you don't know where the result is located (at the end or at the beginning). Came up with this regex (code below), but it selects an equal sign as well which is expected. I can just replace the equal sign with nothing, but it's definitely not the right way to do it. So how to select only a portion of a match?

```
from re import compile,findall

regex = compile(r'(\d+=)?\d+\+\d+(=\d+)?')
print(findall(regex,'1+2=3'))
#Expected: [('', '3')]
#Actual: [('', '=3')]
print(findall(regex,'3=1+2'))
#Expected: [('', '3')]
#Actual: [('', '3=')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
matches = re.findall(r'(?<==)\d+$|^\d+(?==)', text)
```

Or to get a single match:

```py
match = re.search(r'(?<==)\d+$|^\d+(?==)', text)
if match:
    print(match.group())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EaO83G/2). *Details*:

- `(?<==)\d+$` - a position immediately preceded with a `=`, then one or more digits are consumed and then the end of string should follow
- `|` - or
- `^\d+(?==)` - start of string (`^`), one or more digits, and then a `=` must follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the string of interest as follows:

```
rgx = r'^\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?= *=)|\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$'
```

```
value = re.search(rgx, str).group(0)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1XD1Zw/1)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python demo](https://tio.run/##XY/dCoJAEIXv5ylOErhrupQbEYL4IFkg/agXqYwGBb27jX83Xe35zpw5yzSfrqgr2/fls6m5A9@JMmbEOBHgHESEnnX8AUQIHiYIptEeAcJlPILYwZyxJtwLWnjYme1xXlxwCA6JyR7q7GreW43/0JmI87dodi9pkKS3jUqi1MirE5XE8GL9/ffXLtGjZrQoK8glkRSi4bLqVOvDjQDXlytNe8/4Wijp99Fqk3P9atRWa@r7Hw)

The regular expression, which contains an alternation, first attempts to match (the string representation of) an integer or float that begins at the start of the string, followed by an equals sign, possibly with intervening spaces:

```
^\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?= *=)
```

`(?= *=)` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match of the number is followed by zero or more spaces and then an equal sign.

As we are using `re.search`, which returns only the first match, we are finished if this match succeeds. If the match fails we know that the number must be at the end of the string, hence, the second part of the alternation is:

```
\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

You may wish to hover your cursor over each part of the regular expression at the regex link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Note that this expression does not verify that the string has the required format. For example, it will return `3` if the string were:

```
1+4 = 2+3
```